# AJaxControlToolKit error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

My Error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.
```

Ive searched through stackoverflow and no solution helps my problem.
I am trying to insert a numericupdown extender with a textbox.

I have already changed `ScriptManager` to `ToolkitScriptManager`.

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" CombineScripts="false">
```

I have added this at the top of the master and child page.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

I have removed the `msAJaxBundle` script reference.

Here's my NumericUpDownExtender

```
  <asp:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericUpDownExtender1" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="SortOrderTextBox"  
                        Width="120"  
                        RefValues=""   
                        ServiceDownMethod=""  
                        ServiceUpMethod=""  
                        TargetButtonDownID=""  
                        TargetButtonUpID=""   
                        Minimum = "1"  
                        Maximum = "7" />
```

Comment: Please share error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change "`TagPrefix`" as `asp` is reserved for asp.net controls.

Try this in page.

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>  

<asp:ScriptManager   
            ID="ScriptManager1"  
            runat="server"  
            >  
        </asp:ScriptManager> 

<ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="NumericUpDownExtender1" runat="server"
                        TargetControlID="SortOrderTextBox"  
                        Width="120"  
                        RefValues=""   
                        ServiceDownMethod=""  
                        ServiceUpMethod=""  
                        TargetButtonDownID=""  
                        TargetButtonUpID=""   
                        Minimum = "1"  
                        Maximum = "7" />
```

http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/11/ajax-numericupdownextender-how-to-use.html

Make sure you've added AjaxControlToolkit.dll to project and added below in web.config.

```
<system.web>
<pages>       <controls>         <add tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"></add>       </controls>     </pages>
</system.web>
```

http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/3-Different-ways-to-add-AjaxControlToolkit-in-Asp

Comment: Still getting same error. I have added everything you listed.

Comment: Ok, when I did that it said <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" CombineScripts="false"> is not a known element and then I changed asp to ajaxToolkit and got the original error. Also the dll file was already in the project